# R extract monthly data and assign it to wet/dry season

Tags: r

[precipitation data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDSgm.png)

i have monthly mean precipitation data for Mexico from 1901-2015 (excel file with headers precipitation, month and year) and would like to extract months 6-10 (with their corresponding year and precipitation) and assign it to the wet season and months 11-5 to the dry season. How can i do it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `%in%` with `ifelse`.  Create a logical vector with `%in%` and assign 'wet season' where the 'Month' is from 6:10 or `else` return as 'dry season'

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
   mutate(Season = ifelse(Month %in% 6:10, 'wet season', 'dry season'))
```

Comment: thanks how can i create a dataframe with wet and dry seasons seperated to plot the data?

Comment: just subset the data by wet or dry you can use it for plot or you can use Facet wrap to display two plots together